# Оглушение согласных после гласных

Tags: фонетика

Как-то давно покупал мороженое. Того что мне нужно не оказалось и мне предложили эскимо [маk]. С латинской "k" я написал слово, потому, что я воспринял название как шотландскую приставку к фамилии (Мак-Клауд, Мак-Кетчон, Мак-Кинли), а не "маг" или "мак", как по идее должен был бы воспринять, называлось "маг".

Тогда меня заинтересовал вопрос, а полностью ли оглушаются согласные? По личным ощущениям и небольшим опытам над друзьями создаётся ощущение, что если перед согласной в слабом положении стоит гласная, то полного редуцирования не происходит, и звуки можно различить. Так ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По  моему  даже  в  слабой  позиции  полностью  не  оглушается.  "Буг  под  маг"  всё  же  и  на  слух  и  в  произношении   не  "бук  под  мак".  Может  это  стремление  разграничить  омофоны.

Answer (score 1):

Никогда ни о чем подобном не слушал. 
В нормативном языке все согласные, имеющие пару по звонкости-глухости (т.е. кроме Н, М, Р и Л) на концах слов всегда оглушаются, если нет регрессивной ассимиляции от последующего слова. Ни о каком неполном оглушении речи не идет.
В некоторых говорах не происходит оглушения конечного В, особенно после О, но тогда правильнее будет говорить о том, что В там произносится как неслоговое У, подобное тому, что есть в белорусском (в других позициях).

Что такое слабое положение согласной?

Comment: Не перед гласным звуком.
 Я тоже об этом ничего не слышал, но в речи это явление ощущаю. Лес и лез, маг и мак, гриб и грипп воспринимаются верно, даже если из контекста определить, какое слово имелось в виду невозможно.

Comment: Мужчины! С праздником! Желаю Вам быть умными, сильными и великодушными!

Comment: Слабая позиция согласных - на конце слова и перед другим согласным. Сильная - перед гласным.

Comment: >Слабая позиция согласных  
  
Можно догадаться, но в нашем контектсе - сомнительно. У автора - "слабое положение". Вообще термин неудачный, имхо.